# Triggering the Feed Import module

Tags: 7, feeds, cron, rules

I have a `Drupal 7` website that is intend to be fed by a `JSON` file.
This file, is actually processed and updated by a `ETL` tool that runs periodically (each 3 hours by example).

Once my `ETL` tool has processed the output JSON file, I need a way to tell the Drupal `Feeds` module to start the import.

Is it possible ? Or do I need to do this with `CRON` ?

Ideally, this job would be trigged by a specific URL call (just like the CRON can be called manually by visiting a specific url).

Comment: 1. use hook_menu to define you own path.
2. write function using docs http://drupal.org/node/622700 to parse your data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @Gaydabura clues, I've created a module.
Here's the answer :

**1. use hook_menu to define you own path**

```
function toot_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['toot/import'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'toot_callback',
    'title' => 'Import tool',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );
  return $items;
}
```

**2. write function using docs to parse your data**

```
function toot_callback($key = '') {
  if ($key != 'defined_key') {
    return t('Unauthorized access');
  }
  else {
    $myFeed = feeds_source('feed_unique_id');
    while (FEEDS_BATCH_COMPLETE != $myFeed->import());
    return t('Import successfull');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For triggering a feeds importer programmatically -

1) Load the feeds source using [feeds_source()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!feeds!feeds.module/function/feeds_source/7) - by passing argument importer id [it is the machine name of the importer; you can find it in the table 'feeds_source']

```
$feeds_source = feeds_source([importer_id]);
```

2) Set up the configuration -

```
$feeds_config = $feeds_source->getConfigFor($feeds_source->importer->fetcher);
$feeds_config['source'] = $url;//url of file | url of site
```

3) Set configurations to feeds source

```
$feeds_source->setConfigFor($feeds_source->importer->fetcher, $feeds_config);
$feeds_source->save();
```

4) Start the import

```
$feeds_source->startImport();
```

I have implemented this for fetching data from url. Haven't tried with file, but this should work with may be some minor changes in the config part.

Else I think you can trigger the feeds using cron too. [Elysia Cron](http://drupal.org/project/elysia_cron) is a great module which gives 'fine grain control over each task and several ways to add custom cron jobs to your site'.

I hope this is of help.

Comment: this is basically what I've done. What I couldn't find was the configuration part ! Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Do you know the difference between `startImport()` and `import()` ?

Comment: @Jean-MichelGarcia I haven't yet found what import() does. Btw, this is a great article on programmatically executing a feeds importer - http://nodesforbreakfast.com/article/2012/09/23/programmatically-execute-feeds-importer-drupal-7