# Execute Drupal Feeds Import Programatically - Where to put code

Tags: feeds

I found this code for executing feeds importers programatically:

```
<?php

// Define the id (machine name) of the importer you want to use.
$importer_id = 'my_feeds_importer';

// Load the Feeds Source object.
$source = feeds_source($importer_id);

// Override configurations... (more on that in a moment)

// Execute the import.
$source->startImport();

?>
```

I'm just not sure where this code is supposed to go (I'm still pretty green when it comes to Drupal!).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have found the code from this [link](http://nodesforbreakfast.com/article/2012/09/23/programmatically-execute-feeds-importer-drupal-7). In this case you can mention this code in a custom function or hook_cron or in a separate page. Totally depends upon you.

Follow 
[Triggering the Feed Import module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/56751/triggering-the-feed-import-module)
and
[Programmatically execute FEED import](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/90062/programmatically-execute-feed-import)